# Multiple choice quiz that repeats answers that you have gotten incorrect, then starts again when you have answered them all correctly

Tags: python, string

I'm pretty new to programming (been learning for about 2 weeks) and my goal is to eventually design a revision-style, multiple-choice quiz that randomly generates questions and repeats the questions that you have gotten wrong.

This I can do, however I have come to a dead end! I would like the user to have the option to repeat the set of questions again after completing the whole set of questions correctly.

```
import random
p2_qns = []
p2_qns.append(["what is 1?", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a"])
p2_qns.append(["what is 2?", "a", "b", "c", "d", "b"])
p2_qns.append(["what is 3?", "a", "b", "c", "d", "c"])

end_2 = False
zero = [0]*len(p2_qns)

def questions():
   end_1 = False
    while end_1 == False:
        p2_qnsc = p2_qns
        #This section picks a random question and asks it
        qn = random.randrange(len(p2_qnsc))
        #this if statement checks to see if the question has alread been          answered correctly.
        if p2_qnsc[qn] != 0:            
            print(p2_qnsc[qn][0],p2_qnsc[qn][1],p2_qnsc[qn][2],p2_qnsc[qn] [3],p2_qnsc[qn][4] )
            #ask for answer and compare it to where the answer is stored
            ans = input("answer:")
            if ans.lower() == p2_qnsc[qn][5]:
                print("correct!")
                #if answer is correct set the whole question to 0 to stop it being asked again
                p2_qnsc[qn] = 0    
            else:
               print("wrong!")
        elif p2_qnsc == zero:
            end_1 = True

while end_2 == False:            
    questions()
    ans = input("Whant to go again? y,n :")
    if ans.lower() == "n":
        end_2 = True
    elif ans.lower() == "y":
        print("starting again")
```

So far my code will ask my 3 questions, repeating them if they are answered incorrectly, but once they've all been answered it will just keep asking if you want to start again if you select `"y"`.

Any help would be most appreciated - but please bear in mind I'm pretty new to this.  I'm OK with `if`, `while`, `for`, arrays - so if it requires more than this to make it work, I'll need to do some extra work!

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Instead of choosing questions at random, randomize their order at the start and go through the list in sequence. You're then guaranteed not to repeat until you intend to. And of course flag answered questions instead of deleting them, as @DavidHarkness suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're *removing* the questions entirely from the list. Instead, mark them as answered. To do this you need a slot to each question to track this information. When building the list of questions, add a seventh slot and assign it a value of `False`.

```
p2_qns.append(["what is 1?", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", False])
p2_qns.append(["what is 2?", "a", "b", "c", "d", "b", False])
p2_qns.append(["what is 3?", "a", "b", "c", "d", "c", False])
```

When the user gets the correct answer, mark it:

```
p2_qnsc[qn] = 0
```

becomes

```
p2_qnsc[qn][6] = True
```

When testing if a question is open for asking, check this field:

```
if p2_qnsc[qn] != 0:
```

becomes

```
if not p2_qnsc[qn][6]:
```

Finally, at the end when the user decides to go through the questions again, clear the changes you made above:

```
for question in p2qnsc:
    question[6] = False
```

> **Notes:** Assigning `p2_qns` to `p2_qnsc` doesn't make a copy of the list. All the changes you make to it are made to `p2_qns` as well since they both reference the same list. For that reason, you can replace all occurrences of `p2_qnsc` with `p2_qns` and drop the `p2_qnsc = p2_qns` line.
>
> There are many opportunities to improve this code, and there are much better ways of reducing the list of questions to avoid repeatedly choosing the same already-answered question over and over (the randomness in the loop), but that will involve dictionaries. Once you have this code working, you could learn a lot by posting a new question to Code Review.